# TextView changes size when i use setText()

Tags: android

I have 2 questions:

1) 
I have several TextView created this way

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listaNumeriTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

When I call setText(), the size of the TextView changes according to the lenght of my text. I tried to call invalidate() but i still have the same problem. How can i solve it?

2) i thought i can set the width of my TextView according to the screen size. For example, if i have 2 TextView on the same line, I can do this textViewSize =  screenSize/2.
Is this a correct way to set Views width?

Comment: You can probably decide the number of characters you want to show in a single line of a text view . You can use a \n at the place you want the text to appear in the next line. Example - textView.setText("FirstLine \n SecondLine \n  Third Line").

Comment: do you mean the TextSize or TextWidth ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1)Response to the First Question :*** 
you can use a specific `width` for your `TextView` instead of `wrap_content` ( the same thing for the height if you want to limit it to an x size) :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listaNumeriTextView"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

***2) Response to the Second Question :*** 
you can use `android:layout_weight` to specify that both of `TextViews` should take the half of the screen size like this :

```
<LinearLayout bla bla 
   bla bla bla 
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="TextView 1"/>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView 1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
LayoutParams params = aboutmetxt.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = 100;
                aboutmetxt.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I used this to set the height

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listaNumeriTextView"
    android:layout_width="XXX"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

XXX specify the width you want to keep. It will be constant than.
Eg : 100dp